# How can I create rounded square corners in Pixelate Mosaic effect?

Tags: photoshop-effects, effects, pixelation

How can I create this Rounded pixelate effect from [Paramount Plus's Instagram post?](https://www.instagram.com/p/CfCpj_EFLIE/)

[image]

Any Graphics design or Motion Design tool that you know of that can achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

This is for Photoshop

1. Apply the mosaic filter to a smart object, cell size 50px. Duplicate the Smart Object
2. Define a custom pattern (50px x 50px), using a rounded rectangle, like this

[image]

3. Fill a new transparent layer under the top copy of the Smart Object with the custom pattern you made, and clip the top smart object to this pattern layer
4. Move the bottom Smart Object about 12px left and 12px down, using the arrow keys to nudge it.

[image]

If you want to create an animation for different sizes of pixel, just repeat the same, but use a different cell size and pattern size. Should be easy enough to just change the mosaic filter size since the filter is non destructive. But, you'll need to prepare different pattern sizes for the different rounded pixel sizes obviously.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It's good enough. So it wasn't as automatic as I think it is. 
I still think there must be some sort of plugin about this on some design tool, somewhere, because look at the randomness and connecting of the Rounded square pixels [here](https://share.cleanshot.com/8ZuRKL). Appreciate this answer though.

Comment: @StevenMancera - Thanks, you're welcome! Sure, the effect might have be done using something automatic. There are literally hundreds of image editing apps for phones and hundreds of Photoshop plugins and other image editors for computers too. It's entirely possible such a thing exists, if finding a needle in a haystack is any help. LOL